# Estou tentando fazer um sistema de logs em PHP/JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, ip

Estou tentando montar um sistemas de logs em PHP e JavaScript que captura o ip interno da máquina do visitante, porém não consigo retornar o valor da variável em JavaScript para a variável em PHP que salva os logs. Podem me ajudar?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var RTCPeerConnection = window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection;

if (RTCPeerConnection) (function () {
    var rtc = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers:[]});
    if (1 || window.mozRTCPeerConnection) {
        rtc.createDataChannel('', {reliable:false});
    };

    rtc.onicecandidate = function (evt) {
        if (evt.candidate) grepSDP("a="+evt.candidate.candidate);
    };
    rtc.createOffer(function (offerDesc) {
        grepSDP(offerDesc.sdp);
        rtc.setLocalDescription(offerDesc);
    }, function (e) { console.warn("offer failed", e); });


    var addrs = Object.create(null);
    addrs["0.0.0.0"] = false;
    function updateDisplay(newAddr) {
        if (newAddr in addrs) return;
        else addrs[newAddr] = true;
        var displayAddrs = Object.keys(addrs).filter(function (k) { return addrs[k]; });
        document.getElementById('list').textContent = displayAddrs.join(" or perhaps ") || "n/a";
    }

    function grepSDP(sdp) {
        var hosts = [];
        sdp.split('\r\n').forEach(function (line) {
            if (~line.indexOf("a=candidate")) {
                var parts = line.split(' '),
                    addr = parts[4],
                    type = parts[7];
                if (type === 'host') updateDisplay(addr);
            } else if (~line.indexOf("c=")) {
                var parts = line.split(' '),
                    addr = parts[2];
                updateDisplay(addr);
            }
        });
    }
})(); else {
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = "<code>ifconfig | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | cut -d\" \" -f2 | tail -n1</code>";
    document.getElementById('list').nextSibling.textContent = "In Chrome and Firefox your IP should display automatically, by the power of WebRTCskull.";
}

</script>
```

Preciso que o ip pego pelo JavaScript entre na variável `$ip`.

```
<?php 
$ip = "IP PEGO PELO JAVASCRIPT";
$data = date("d/m/Y");

if ($file = fopen("ips.txt","a+")){
        fputs($file,"Dia de entrada: ".$data." IP:".$ip. "\n");
}else {
        $file = fopen("ips.txt","a+");
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: amigo pq no javascript tu n faz um post no arquivo php, e ai no php vc recupera o post pra guardar o log

Comment: porem nao tenho ideia de como fazer isso amigo, eu nao sou bom em javascript :/

Comment: pq precisa ser em javascript? Eu faço tudo em php,vou te mostrar

Comment: esse script captura o ip interno, LAN acho meio dificil fazer isso com php, eu tenho um que captura ip REAL,porem preciso registrar os ip's internos.

Comment: tenho uma intranet que com esse script pego os ips locais tbm

Comment: amigo se qual é o objetivo desse pedido pq se guardar no banco pode ser uma solução tbm a depender da necessidade tipo um sistema de login vc guarda ip agent hora etc

Comment: amigo se eu conseguir guardar esses ips em um txt pra mim fica tranquilo de manipular o resto com python >.<

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução em php

```
//Recupera o IP real
function getIp() {

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];

    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];

    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    return $ip;
}
```

.

```
    //Cria o log se der erro na pasta der acesso chmod 777
    function logUsuario(){ 

        $data = date("d-m-Y H-i-s");
        $ip = getIp(); 
        $msg = "[".$data."]\n\nIP: " . $ip . ""; 
        $fp = fopen("/logs/IP_USUARIO_".$data.".txt",'a+'); 
        fwrite($fp,$msg); 
        fclose($fp); 
    }


    //para usar só chamar a função onde vc queira
    logUsuario();
```

Comment: amigo eu ja possuo um script que faz a mesma funcao porem a vantagem do meu javascript eh que pego o ip interno! esse script pega somente o ip externo (que nao necessito) mesmo assim obg!

Comment: esse script eu pego interno na intranet. Se em javascript vc pega logicamente php vc pegaria mas tudo bem